# Accessing methods and variables in java

Tags: java, class, constructor, reference

Basically, in my app, I have a class called **Resources** which is where I create and hold all of my objects.

When I create an object, let's call it myObject, I need to be able to access various methods and /or variables from the resource class, so at the moment, I am doing something like this:

```
public class Resources {

    int height;  //This will hold the height of the current device's screen (in pixels).  For the purpose of this question, please assume this has been intialised at some point.

    public void createObjects(){

        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(this); //Pass reference to this (Resources) class into constructor

    }

    public void method1(){

       //Do something here, this method could do some work or could be a proxy method to another class

    }

}
```

So my 'MyObject' class would look something like so:

```
public class MyObject{

    Resources resources;    
    int yPosition;

    public MyObject(Resources resources){

        this.resources  = resources;

    }

    public intialise(){

        //Some examples
        resources.method1();
        yPosition = (resources.height)/2;

    }

}
```

As I said, my Resources class is just that - it holds all of my objects and other important information (such as screen size etc.) so I need to access this class from within the objects that I create (so I can keep all code relating to that object within the object itself rather than externally (directly in the Resources class for example which would be really messy).

I've been doing this and it hasn't caused any issues, and I realise that I'm simply passing a reference to my 'resources' object, what I would like to know is, is this an 'acceptable' way to access that which I need to?

Comment: This type of questions is better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.  They love to discuss using factories instead of explicit constructors and all such stuff.

Comment: @PM77-1 This is what we would call *example code*, which is not something that we would like to "discuss". This would be off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg - That's interesting to know.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion would be to post the *real code* on Code Review and ask for a review on that. It is likely that Code Review users can suggest a better way of doing things when being faced against the real code with real context. And while they're at it, they might discover something else that can be improved as well.